# How to run PowerShell cmdlets from custom PS modules when deploying a new Azure VM?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, executionpolicy

Is it possible to install a custom PowerShell module in Azure VM post-deployment task and run PS cmdlets from that module in this task?

I have a Bicep template that deploys a new Windows Azure VM. The template has a `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2020-12-01` post-deployment resource that takes these steps:

1. Installs an MSI-packaged application (with a new custom PowerShell module) using `Start-Process` (OK)
2. Creates several folders via PowerShell (OK)
3. Runs several cmdlets installed at step 1 (**NOT OK**)

Running a cmdlet from the custom module in the post-deployment script shows the following error in the "Extensions + applications" log:

`... is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ...`

When I change the post-deployment step to `Import-Module MODULENAME`, I see another message:

`Import-Module : The specified module 'MODULENAME' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module \r\ndirectory.`

When I run `Get-Module` in the post-deployment task, I see only these two modules listsd:

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                             
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                             
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Con...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
```

So the module is not getting loaded.

**But when I remote to the deployed VM, I run the cmdlets from the custom PowerShell module without any errors.**

I think that my scenario is supported, but I don't quite understand how to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: Perhaps the module has not finished installing yet?  Has step 3 been set up to depend on step 1?  Also does step one complete after calling msi installation or does it wait until completion?

Comment: What happens if you try `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name 'MODULENAME'` which will also list unloaded modules.  While you are at it might as well check `$env:PSModulePath` also.  Make sure the directory that your module gets installed to is in there.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! You were right. It appears that the modules hasn't been installed yet when the script tries to run other cmdlets. So everything works as expected. I just need to modify the script to wait until installation has finished. Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75201677/761095 Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem with these two steps:

1. I've added `-Wait` to `Start-Process` and this has resolved the problem.
2. I've added a path to the module into PSModulePath and ran `$Env:PSModulePath = $Env:PSModulePath+";PATH-TO-MODULE"`
   `Import-Module MODULENAME -Force`. Normally, the installed does this step for me. But it appears that I need to run these commands manually because all this is done in a single PowerShell session.

It appears that the problem was with my `customScript.ps1` script. The very first line of the script installs an MSI-packaged application that adds the required PowerShell module:

```
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList @('/i', 'msi-installer-name.msi', '/qb')
```

PowerShell starts the installation using `Start-Process` and continues. So when I'm running these commands, the installation hasn't yet finished:

```
$env:PSModulePath | Out-File C:\Temp\psmodulepath.txt
Get-Module -ListAvailable | Out-File C:\Temp\getmodulelistavailable.txt
```